# Why won't my air register fit back in its hole? Why's it jutting out?

Tags: register

Since I moved in 7 years ago, nothing bulged out! I never touched my metal air [Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28air_and_heating%29) that fit its hole perfectly, until today.

Today, after pulling it out to clean it, **why can't I push it back in? Why's it poking out?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have insulated air vents, good for you.

Unfortunately they are made of flimsy metal housing (bend easy and loose shape)

Use few nails (with large head) and put some (inside) into the vent nailing it to the wood frame.

Get some sheet metal nails aka roofing nails
Now nail it inside the hvac tube about 1 inch from the edge in to the wooden frane. That will keep it in place.

I found example for floor register, same applies for the wall register.

[image: register]

Comment: Can you draw a picture for your last sentence? I can't picture what you mean. thanks.

Comment: @user165003 added more description, sorry my drawing skills suck

Comment: How do you know that I can nail through the metal? What if the metal is too hard or thick? And if I nail the vent to the wood frame, then how can I handily remove the vent? Like for cleaning every year?

Comment: @user165003  Ruskes meant for you to nail the very thin metal duct that is inside of the hole in the wall, not the outside vent cover.

Comment: @crip659 Please draw on my picture to indicate the "the very thin metal duct that is inside of the hole in the wall" ? I don't know where you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have an edge(s) of the duct interfering with an edge(s) of the register.  Bend one or both out of the way so that the register fits flush with the wall.

Edit:
[image]
[image]
See pics.  One of the red lines is interfering with one of the blue lines.  You'll have to figure out which one(s) it is.

Comment: Please draw on my picture to indicate the "edge(s) of the duct interfering with an edge(s) of the register" ? I don't know where you are talking about.

Comment: @user165003 - Something on the edge of the register is catching on something on the edge of the duct boot (in the wall). Since you're the one there in person, you'll have to look at them to see where there might be a bit of one or the other (or both) sticking out, then attempt to bend it back so that it no longer interferes with easily sliding the two together. Look around the spot where the register doesn't go all the way to the wall - make a light pencil mark if necessary, then pull it apart again and look for something that's not straight.

Comment: I believe that the middle picture is the duct boot in the wall. To my eye, the top of that boot looks wrinkled and is the most likely candidate for _some_ part of it sticking far enough down into the opening that it's preventing the register from smoothly sliding back in. Also, look at the part of the register that slides into the wall. If you see scratch marks on it, that's a likely spot where metal is rubbing against metal. You're going to have to do some investigation on your own, we can't just magically tell you from the other side of the internet that your problem is "here".